# docker compose, vagrant and insecure Repository

Tags: docker, vagrant, docker-compose

I have setup docker-compose to pull my image from a custom repository.

Here is how the yaml file looks like

```
my_service:
  image: d-myrepo:5000/mycompany/my_service:latest
  ports:
    - "8079:8079"
```

Now if I run vagrant up, it gets errors

==> default:   File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/docker.auth.auth", line 46, in expand_registry_url
==> default: docker.errors
==> default: .
==> default: DockerException
==> default: :
==> default: HTTPS endpoint unresponsive and insecure mode isn't enabled.
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f "/vagrant/docker-compose.yml" up -d

Stdout from the command:



Stderr from the command:

stdin: is not a tty
Creating vagrant_y2y_1...
Pulling image d-myrepo:5000/mycompany/my_service:latest...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.main", line 31, in main
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.docopt_command", line 21, in sys_dispatch
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.command", line 27, in dispatch
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.docopt_command", line 24, in dispatch
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.command", line 59, in perform_command
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.cli.main", line 464, in up
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.project", line 208, in up
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.service", line 214, in recreate_containers
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/compose.service", line 197, in create_container
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/docker.client", line 710, in pull
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/docker.auth.auth", line 67, in resolve_repository_name
  File "/code/build/docker-compose/out00-PYZ.pyz/docker.auth.auth", line 46, in expand_registry_url
docker.errors.DockerException: HTTPS endpoint unresponsive and insecure mode isn't enabled.
```

I read about it on the internet, that it has to do with having an insecure repo.

It only works, only if I edit the file

```
/etc/default/docker
```

with content

```
DOCKER_OPTS="-r=true --insecure-registry d-myrepo:5000 ${DOCKER_OPTS}"
```

restart the docker service and manually pull the image. i.e.

```
docker pull d-myrepo:5000/mycompany/my_service:latest
```

Is there a way to avoid this error? and having the provisioning running smoothly? maybe I am missing an option inside the `docker-composer.yml` file?

Comment: Does `docker-compose` still complain after you changed the `DOCKER_OPTS`?

Comment: If i do `vagrant reload` after manually pulling the image, the provisioning runs without errors:     `default: Running docker-compose up...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Creating vagrant_my_service_1...`

Comment: Then you need to modify the docker options before vagrant uses docker. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29290807/390808

Comment: the solution you gave did not work, but when i login into the vagrant machine, and do the following command, the repos get pulled perfectly. `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f "/vagrant/docker-compose.yml" up -d --allow-insecure-ssl` ....Is there i can integrate this into my vagrantfile?

Comment: I assume you are using the docker-compose vagrant plugin https://github.com/leighmcculloch/vagrant-docker-compose. Looking at the code, there seems to be no way passing additional options to docker-compose from the vagrant file. Also there seems to be no (documented) way to pass default options to docker-compose. Therefore I see no way doing this.

Comment: @SvenKoschnicke I like the idea of allowing options to be passed through, I'll add the ability to do this to the plugin. Follow along if you'd like: https://github.com/leighmcculloch/vagrant-docker-compose/issues/10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

thanks for your feedack, the best way to achieve this is to set the vagrant provisioning the following way

```
  config.vm.provision :docker
  config.vm.provision :docker_compose
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision.sh", privileged: false
```

while the shell script `provision.sh` would include the following relevant lines.

```
sudo echo "DOCKER_OPTS=\"-r=true --insecure-registry my_repo:5000 \${DOCKER_OPTS}\"" | sudo tee /etc/default/docker
sudo  service docker restart
sudo /usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /vagrant/docker-compose.yml up -d --allow-insecure-ssl
```

Comment: Glad that it works now! Are you sure that the shell command doesn't need to be put *before* the docker_compose provisioner? The manual states that multiple provisioners are executed in the order of their appearance in the vagrant file https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/basic_usage.html